# How to submit search form using Bootstrap 3 drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to submit the input form, dropdown li data-action and the input hidden. I am using Bootstrap 3.

Below is the HTML code. Code is also [available on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtest/gpba5z7d/).

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 hidden-xs search-section">
  <div id="search-div">
    <h2 class="hidden">Search</h2>
    <label class="hidden" for="edit-search-keys">Enter the terms you wish to search for. </label>
    <form method="GET" action="http://google.com" class="search-form navbar-form navbar-right">
      <div class="input-group custom-search-form ">
        <input class="form-control" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Search all sites" tabindex="2" aria-labelledby="Search
all sites" title="Search all sites" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">GO <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#" data-action="option_01">option 01</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-action="option_02">option 02</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input name="client" value="01" type="hidden" >
      <input name="output" value="02" type="hidden">
      <input name="proxystylesheet" value="03" type="hidden">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
  <li><a class="optionclass" href="#" data-action="option_01">option 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-action="option_02">option 02</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
    $('.optionclass').click(function(){
         $('.search-form').submit();
    });
```